# Horizontal scroll area for displaying code snippets on tumblr

Tags: css, tumblr, prettify, google-code-prettify

I am trying to set up my tumblr theme using prettify and css customization to display python code snippets. I am brand new to css, but I have it pretty much working as I want now (thanks to scouring the web for examples). However, the text is wrapping when too long and I have not been able to figure out how to get it to just display a scroll bar instead.

```
        pre code {
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            display: block;
            line-height: 1.6em;
        font-size: 11px;
        }
```

Here is what I am using right now. I found some pages saying I wanted to add white-space: to here, but after going through all the options, none of them seem to work. The option nowrap makes it so there are no linebreaks whatsoever.

If I add width: 2000px or something huge, it stops the text from wrapping but it gets written over top of everything and no scroll bar appears.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is correct? I.e. you have `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.  Because this works for me...http://jsbin.com/alADiKo/1/edit

Comment: Pretty sure. The code snippets are successfully getting formatted by prettify. Interesting to see that it is in fact working on that page. I wonder if the tumblr theme is somehow overriding the behaviour.The one difference I notice between your code on that page and the code in the theme is there is no container set anywhere. Not sure if that makes any difference. I should also mention, I am still just set to the default tumblr theme Optica.

Comment: Ah ok, it's the theme I think. I just previewed the theme and tested adding your HTML.  In your CSS, try adding: `white-space: pre;
word-wrap: normal;`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Never would have gotten that. Gotta look up what is special about that combination now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem.  The code I gave in the comment above is setting the properties back to their default values.

Comment: @davidpauljunior, how does that compare to `white-space: pre-wrap`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel `pre-wrap` will wrap when necessary and on line breaks, `pre` will only wrap on line breaks.

Comment: @davidpauljunior, does `word-wrap:normal` affect the wrapping behavior `white-space:pre`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel with `word-wrap: normal` and `white-space: pre` the text will _only_ wrap when there are line breaks in the content.  When using `word-wrap: break-word` and `white-space: pre`, behaviour seems to be the same as `break-word` and `pre-wrap` combo.  I've listed them all out here. http://jsbin.com/OSuNatep/1/edit

Comment: @davidpauljunior, nice!

Answer (score 6):

In order to get it work with coloring syntax.

Go to: Customize > Custom Theme (Edit HTML)
And in your HTML template code add this just before head tag:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

    pre code {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        font-size: 11px;
        white-space: pre; 
        word-wrap: normal;
    }
</style>

<!-- For Syntax Highlighting -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.css"></link>  
<script src="http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js"></script>  
<script>
    function styleCode() {
        if (typeof disableStyleCode != 'undefined') { return; }

        var a = false;

        $('code').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('prettyprint')) {
                $(this).addClass('prettyprint');
                a = true;
            }
        });

        if (a) { prettyPrint(); } 
    }

    $(function() {styleCode();});
</script>
```